# Merging two data.tables by condition

Tags: r, merge, data.table

I know there is one way to do this:

```
library(data.table)
X = data.table(x = c(1,1,1,2,2,5,6))
Y = data.table(y = c(2,5))
X[Y, .N, on=.(x>=y), by=.EACHI]
```

Which should yield:

```
   x N
1: 2 4
2: 5 2
```

But what if I want to do a more complex condition like this?

```
X[Y, .N, on=.(x>=y & x<=y+3), by=.EACHI]
```

This won't work, as I get the following error:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(X, Y, .N, on = .(x >= y & x <= y + 3), by = .EACHI) : 
  Column(s) [y & x] not found in i
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: You could make a temporary variable `xplus3` which is equal to `x+3` and then do the join?

Comment: There is an open feature request for that (Frank just added a back link to the issue): https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1639